# How to use Windows PowerShell Write-Progress with a range larger than 100 in for loop

Tags: powershell, for-loop

Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7.1

Example 1 from documentation throws error when more than 100 given in a condition.

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10000; $i++ )
{
    Write-Progress -Activity "Search in Progress" -Status "$i% Complete:" -PercentComplete $i
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
}
```

Error:
Write-Progress : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'PercentComplete'. The {101} argument is greater than the maximum allowed range of 100. Supply an argument that is less than or equal to 100 and then
try the command again.

how to convert this 10000 to a value less than 100 to show progress of the for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the [progress percentage in each iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7.1#example-3--display-the-progress-while-searching-for-a-string).

```
($i/$total*100)
```

So you might have to change your code like this,

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10000; $i++ )
{
    $PercentCompleted = ($i/10000*100)
    Write-Progress -Activity "Search in Progress" -Status "$PercentCompleted% Complete:" -PercentComplete $PercentCompleted
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
}
```

Comment: You'll want to update `"$i% Complete:"` too